# One function to describe them all

Tags: c++

I have a class

```
class A
{
private:
   Type m_obj1;
   Type m_obj2;
   ....
   Type m_objN;

   void Init()
   {
      m_obj1=Value1;
      m_obj2=Value2;
      ....
   }
public:
   Type GetObj1(){return m_obj1;}
   Type GetObj2(){return m_obj1;}
   Type GetObj3(){return m_obj1;}
   ....
};
```

Those variables and Get methods keep repeated 6 times. Is there a neat way to generalise them all into one method then if I insert an interger e.g 3, it'll call `GetObj3`.

Comment: An `std::map<int, Type>`, perhaps?

Comment: While this is a funny title, it's not a very good one.

Comment: How about `std::vector` or `std::array`?

Comment: If it has getters and setters for each data member, it's not a class, it's a struct. And a struct containing only one type is usually better written as a data container of some sort.

Comment: For GetObj1, GetObj2 and GetObj3 it's easy. they all do the same.

Comment: Don't write [pseudo-classes](http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf). An array of `Type` objects is better than this\.

Comment: @DevSolar: _"If it has getters and setters for each data member, it's not a class, it's a struct."_ Huh? Where did you hear that?!

Comment: @jrok That article is awesome.

Comment: This post: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/11/20/seven-virtues-of-good-object.html is nice as well.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The article jrok linked to puts it into words much better than I could.

Comment: @DevSolar: jrok's article doesn't even _contain_ the word "struct". So what are you talking about?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Oh **jeeez**, really? You don't see any similarity between OP's `class A` and Weisert's `class Thing`? All it does is *grouping* several objects. So it's a struct, or an array (see **your very own answer**), or some other kind of data container -- but not a class.

Comment: @DevSolar: You are the only person here making some sort of judgement about when something is "a struct" but not "a class". The article doesn't even come close to suggesting that. It appears to be entirely nonsensical as far as I can tell. There is no such thing as "a struct" as distinct from "a class" in C++ — the keywords `struct` and `class`, despite inviting different access defaults, both result in the same entity: a user-defined type (or "a class", colloquially). Can you expand on why you think that there is some kind of distinction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
Type m_obj1;
Type m_obj2;
....
Type m_objN;
```

How about you have a single member

```
std::map<int, Type> m _obj;
```

Then you can store and lookup your variables based on the index you are describing.

Or as @jrok mentioned, if you can use a `std::vector` or `std::array` and just use the index of the element to look them up. Anything with random access will allow you to get at your element in `O(1)` time

```
std::vector<Type> m_obj;
```

Answer (score 9):

You appear to be reinventing arrays.

Cyber and jrok have made some good suggestions, but in fact this *entire* class is completely useless.

Replace `A` with `std::vector<Type>` (or `std::array<Type, Count>`, possibly) and be done with it!
It does what you're trying to do, but better.

Comment: I'd like to choose your and Cybor's answers correct ones but seems I can choose only one.

Comment: @user3570552: You should choose the one that helped you most. I'm sorry to see that you've gone for the less optimal of the two solutions, but that's up to you!